# How to get two different objects into a TreeSet?

Tags: java, treeset

I am unable to get two different `objects` into a `TreeSet` if one's

```
compareTo(the other)==0.
```

Can some one help in understand this and how can i achieve it in tree set .

```
 public class Test

{
    private static SortedSet sortedSet = new TreeSet();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sortedSet.add(new IntegerBucket("Winner", 3));
        sortedSet.add(new IntegerBucket("Looser", 3));

        System.out.println("sortedSet has " + sortedSet.size() + " members");
        System.out.println(sortedSet);
    }

}

class IntegerBucket implements Comparable {
    private int value = 0;
    private String name = null;

    public IntegerBucket(String n, int val) {
        name = n;
        value = val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // Comparable interface
    public int compareTo(Object ob) {

        return getValue() - ((IntegerBucket) ob).getValue();

    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + getValue();
    }
}
```

Output of above program is:

```
sortedSet has 1 members
[Winner 3]
```

Comment: Are you sure you defined the `compareTo` method correctly? It's your decision - there's no right and wrong answer - but do you really want "[winner, 3] == [loser, 3]"?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger there's a stronger requirement than that on `Comparable` with `TreeSet`.... see the quote in my answer.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, it is: your quote says "It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that [compare should be consistent with equality]"; `TreeSet` says "Note that the ordering maintained by a set ... **must** be consistent with equals".

Comment: Your quote says that, whilst not recommended, it is allowable for a general comparator to have `(x.compareTo(y)==0) != (x.equals(y))`. But `TreeSet` *does not* allow the use of such a comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, by the contract of the `TreeSet` class.

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.)

If you have different objects (i.e. `!a.equals(b)`) for which `a.compare(b)` or `comparator.compare(a, b)` is zero, you're violating this contract.

The only way you can do it (indirectly) is to pass in a `Comparator` when constructing the `TreeSet` (e.g. `new TreeSet<>(someComparator)` which tie-breaks between the objects, i.e. causes the result of `compare(a, b)` to be non-zero.

Comment: Can you please explain when you say tie-breaks..:Thanks in advnace

Comment: "i.e. causes the result of compare(a, b) to be non-zero"

Comment: The TreeSet considers elements to be equal when compareTo returns 0. So non-equal objects have to return a non-zero value. And that value (and the ordering it imposes on the space of possible objects) has to be complete and consistent (otherwise your TreeSet will also not behave properly).